# Get Dialogfragment result

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an activity that call a dialogfragment, how can I get the fragment result when it dismissed? Is there any method for fragment like onActivityResult?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a callback to know the response of your dialog fragment. If you want to implement this, create an interface in your dialog fragment. Like this example:

```
interface OnResultDialog{
    public void onDialogRespond(Object result);
}
private OnResultDialog mCallback;
```

And implement this interface in your activity. In the onAttach of your DialogFragment, set the activity as an OnResultDialog:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallback = (OnResultDialog)activity;
}
```

Then, before or after you dismiss your dialog, you can call the method of your callback and pass the parameters you need. Like this:

```
mCallback.onDialogRespond(object);
```

Hope it helps